# Options to secure website admin panel access - only trusted users access it

Tags: amazon-web-services, security

I want to secure admin panel of ecommerce website such that only trusted users get to access the login page. To avoid any malicious attempts like bruteforce etc.

Storefront and admin panel are hosted on different domains. Complete stack is hosted on AWS. Possible solutions I can think of are:

- Using fixed static IP address is a possible solution but many of our employees access panel from mobile devices outside office, and many from different cities while on travel.
- Employing WAF to restrict login attempts etc. can be employed. But again, possibilities are there for a non trusted user to hack into with dedicated efforts.

I am looking for some way with which any url including login page becomes inaccessible for non trusted users without using IP blocking strategy.

Answer (score 2):

If you need tight security, these are my points for you.

- make the admin website to a private website and make it available only via **VPN**.
- use **WAF** to guard the website from malicious attacks
- as @Daniel mentioned, adding multi factor authentication(**MFA**) is the best way to secure it further.

to make a website private via VPN, You can,

- deploy the website instances and the load balancer on private subnets
- setup a open vpn instance on a public instance
- Setup open vpn login credentials for each admin

Hope this helps

Comment: The great thing about a VPN is that the site is not publicly exposed, so any vulnerabilities in the site's security is not exploitable.  VPN solutions are usually pretty well trusted so it provides meaningful protection.  AWS recently rolled out a Client VPN solution - you may or may not find it cost effective.

Answer (score 1):

two factor authentication with TOTP (note that NIST recommends against SMS strongly, and the rest of the industry should too) is probably the best way to do this without imposing undue burdens on the users. AWS ALBs can do some cool things with authentication these days (from cognito OIDC to full on AWS-style request authorization with signatures) , but none of those things amount to more than a password login.

Answer (score 1):

While the VPN solutions are good, the common approach to what you're describing is a client certificate. Each user is issued a client cert which they store on their machine(s). An approved cert is required to access the page. This is also commonly called "mutual authentication."